# JavaScript RegEx won't match with newline

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm current making a simple application using NodeJS to translate input into a defined format. For this I'm using the following piece of JavaScript, where `content` is the input.

```
content = content.replace(/(.+)\n=+$/gm, '<div>$1</div>');
content = content.replace(/(.+)\n-+$/gm, '<p>$1</p>');
```

Using this, I would expect the code below

```
Message
======

Another Message
------
```

translate into

```
<div>Message</div>

<p>Another Message</p>
```

However, I get the same output as input (so nothing changed),

I tried it with both [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) and WebStorm's RegEx tester, and both of those find a match. When I log the result of `content.match(/(.+)\n=+$/gm)` I get `null`.

When I remove the `\n` from the RegEx and the input, it does seem to match, which has me think the `\n` is causing some kind of issue. However, I'm not aware of any issue this could be causing.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/o92sa1mu/

Comment: ^ same https://regexr.com/43ve3

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your javaScript code. You can test it [here](https://rextester.com/PPY48349)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using windows?

give a try to:

```
content = content.replace(/(.+)\r\n=+$/gm, '<div>$1</div>');
content = content.replace(/(.+)\r\n-+$/gm, '<p>$1</p>');
```

depending on OS and browser you may get there `\n` or `\r\n` (`\r` denotes carriage return, they may be other reasons for them to appear. But in your regex you should expect either `\n` or `\r\n`

**Edit:**

As suggested by [Poul Bak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5741643/poul-bak) you could simply add `?` after `\r` to handle both cases:

```
content = content.replace(/(.+)\r?\n=+$/gm, '<div>$1</div>');
content = content.replace(/(.+)\r?\n-+$/gm, '<p>$1</p>');
```

Comment: Use: '/(.+)\r?\n=+$/gm' That makes the '\r' optional.